# Fitting with keras Model API

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create something similar to Word2Vec with the following:

```py
class Word2Vec(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(
                                vocab_size, 
                                embedding_dim,
                                input_length=1,
                                name="w2v_embedding"
        )
        self.dot = keras.layers.Dot(axes=(-1, -1))

    def call(self, data):
        target, context = data
        we = self.embedding(target)
        ce = self.embedding(context)
        return self.dot([we, ce])
```

and suppose the loss is the following:

```py
def loss(similarity):
    log_prob = tf.math.log(tf.sigmoid(similarity))
    return -tf.math.reduce_mean(log_prob)
```

I am trying to fit to the above model with words and its contexts but running into the error: `OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over` tf.Tensor `is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.`.

Supposing I have a dummy dataset that looks like the following:

```py
N = 10000
V = 100
word = np.random.randint(0, V, N)
context = np.random.randint(0, V, (N, 4))
```

What I tried to do was:

```
word2vec = Word2Vec(V, 32)
word2vec.compile(loss=loss, optimizer="adam")
word2vec.fit(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((word, context)), batch_size=128, epochs=1)
```

when I got the above error. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

I understand that this is not the exact word2vec model, but I'm more concerned about understanding the tensorflow/ keras API and getting this to work, than the actual paper implementation.

### Edit 1

An editable kaggle notebook with full code is available here: https://www.kaggle.com/sachin/word-vectors

Comment: your loss seems to not include the target. it should be loss(target, similarity)... I suggest u this https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/

Comment: Yeah I realise, but in this particular case all targets are true. Hence why I used the custom loss function above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is causing the issue:

```
target, context = data
```

Try this instead:

```
target = data[0]
context = data[1]
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I added a kaggle notebook above if it helps.